# email sends to spam of gmail account

Tags: php

I have set automatically to send email to users from my website. but this email will place to spam of users with gmail accounts.However it is working fine with yahoo or hotmail accounts. 
How should I solve this?

```
$to = "$Email";
$subject = "Greeting";
$message = 'message here';
$from = "sender@example.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: sender@example.com" . "\r\n" .
  "Reply-To: sender@example.com" . "\r\n";            

                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Do you have valid mx records for the server you're sending from (particularly, is the from address a valid email address for your domain)?

Comment: Do you have reverse DNS set up?

Comment: yes, and this just happens recently. it was working fine on gmail accounts before.

Answer (score 0):

Since your headers appear to be correct, it's probably keying on something within the message. One of the things that SpamAssassin (no idea if this is what Gmail uses) keys on is a very short message like the above containing a hyperlink or graphic, so you may benefit by actually making your message a little longer. One of the ways to find out is to send it to your own gmail account and when it appears in your spam folder, examine the headers there for any added spam information. It may contain clues as to what spam engine Gmail is using or what rules your message is breaking.

Please have a look here:

[Spam sent to Contacts -
  Message Delivery](http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-Message-Delivery-en/browse_thread/thread/e5c554347f7f3221)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My message is long but its an html message with images and graphics.However,I cant understand that it was working fine like 1 week ago, and Just now I noticed of this. How can I examine the  header for spam information? thank you

Comment: well it was working fine before and not now, i don't think it will be same as you thinking, try to think other options and I am sure you will find it working as it should

Answer (score 0):

it should be of smtp configuration email and site information email id should be diffrent.